# SQL count at least

Tags: sql, count

I need to find the makers producing at least three distinct models of PCs.
Result set: maker, number of models.

My tables are 
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)

I have done this for now

```
SELECT Product.maker, PC.model 
FROM PC, Product 
WHERE Product.model=PC.model
```

Comment: what engine? MySQL, SQL Server, ...?

Answer (score 5):

`PC` table [contains only the computers having been produced and it may be missing some existing models not yet produced](http://sql-ex.ru/help/select13.php#db_1):

> The table "Product" includes information about the maker, model
>   number, and type ('PC', 'Laptop', or 'Printer'). It is assumed that
>   model numbers in the Product table are unique for all the makers and
>   product types. Each PC uniquely specifying by a code in the table "PC"
>   is characterized by model (foreign key referencing to Product table),
>   speed (of the processor in MHz), total amount of RAM - ram (in Mb),
>   hard disk drive capacity - hd (in Gb), CD ROM speed - cd (for example,
>   '4x'), and the price.

All the models are contained in the `Product` table.

It turns out that `Product` table has the flag what type of product it is: `type`.

So, the query doesn't really even need a join:

```
select maker, count(model)
from Product
where type = 'PC'
group by maker
having count(model) >= 3
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem:
So try this query, hope you are looking for this one:

```
SELECT maker, COUNT(DISTINCT model)
FROM product
WHERE type = 'PC'
GROUP BY maker
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT model) > 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this query:

```
select Product.maker, count(distinct Product.model)
from PC inner join Product on PC.model = Product.model
group by Product.maker
having count(distinct Product.model) >= 3
```

Comment: +1 for correct use of standard SQL aggregate I'd like to add another +1 for explicit join...

Comment: @Darko that means that you don't have such producers that produce at least 3 distinct models of PC :)

Comment: I have one produces with count of 3, why am i not getting that producer?

Comment: @Darko may you post the data for this producer here?

Comment: @Tim here is the data from the Product                          table  maker model type
A 1232 PC
A 1233 PC
A 1276 Printer
A 1298 Laptop
A 1401 Printer
A 1408 Printer
A 1752 Laptop
B 1121 PC
B 1750 Laptop
C 1321 Laptop
D 1288 Printer
D 1433 Printer
E 1260 PC
E 1434 Printer
E 2112 PC
E 2113 PC

Comment: @Darko can you post also the content of PC table? I suppose that there is no foreign key constraint therefore *E 1260 PC*, *E 2112 PC* and *E 2113 PC* are not the result of join between Product and PC table.

Comment: @Tim this is the data from the PC table code model speed ram hd cd price
1 1232 500 64 5.0 12x 600.0000
10 1260 500 32 10.0 12x 350.0000
11 1233 900 128 40.0 40x 980.0000
12 1233 800 128 20.0 50x 970.0000
2 1121 750 128 14.0 40x 850.0000
3 1233 500 64 5.0 12x 600.0000
4 1121 600 128 14.0 40x 850.0000
5 1121 600 128 8.0 40x 850.0000
6 1233 750 128 20.0 50x 950.0000
7 1232 500 32 10.0 12x 400.0000
8 1232 450 64 8.0 24x 350.0000
9 1232 450 32 10.0 24x 350.0000

Comment: @Darko exactly you don't have entries for model **2112** and **2113**, so you have to insert them in the PC table

Comment: @Darko I would suggest to make a foreign key between PC table and Product table.

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
SELECT P.maker, count(P.model) as Count_Model
from product P
where p.type = 'pc'
group by maker
having count(p.model) >=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `GROUP BY Product.maker HAVING COUNT(PC.model) >= 3`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT maker,COUNT(model) AS Count_Models FROM Product 
    WHERE type = 'PC' 
    GROUP BY maker 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT model) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following query:

```
select distinct maker,COUNT(model) AS Count_model from Product where type='PC' GROUP BY maker HAVING COUNT(model)>=3
```